# Sum of na rows when column value is na , and other column value == ""

Tags: r

I've tried to get a simple sum of the row count that have na values in columns 'ip_id' and 'pd_id', where column 'cat' == "Grade 6".

I have this which counts the sum of na's but i wanted to try filter it by na's in columns 1 and column 2 contains "Grade 6".

```
sum(apply(df, 2, anyNA))

[1] 22
```

But think I need something like filter(2 = "Grade 6"). But get errors when i try put this with my apply function.

Does anyone know the steps of how to filter with this function?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda guessing since you didn't provide an example of your dataframe, but using `dplyr` maybe this suits your need:

```
library(dplyr)
nrow(
    filter(df, cat == "Grade 6" & is.na(ip_id) & is.na(pd_id))
)
```

Comment: that was perfect thank you, apologies i should've added a table and mentioned I used tidyverse. thank you so much!